# Trigonometry rewrite

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

How do you go from $$ \frac{ \sin z }{e^z -1} $$ to $$ \frac{\cos z}{e^z}$$

My first approach was to use eulers formula. But that made the calculations quite hard. I'm guessing this can be done easier with some smart rewrite?

Comment: If you take $\displaystyle z=\frac{\pi}{4}$ then $\displaystyle \frac{sin(z)}{e^z-1} \ne \frac{cos(z)}{e^z}$.

Comment: It looks like an application of L'Hospital's rule. Was the task to find the value of $\frac{\sin z}{e^z-1}$ at $0$?

Comment: if you compute derivatives of both functions (I call them $f$ and $g$) then you arrive at $f'(z)=g(z)-f(z)\frac{z}{e^z-1}$. Do you like Bernoulli numbers? :)

Comment: It was a rewrite to be able to get $lim_{z -> 0} \frac{\sin z}{e^z-1} = 1$

Comment: What I said, @iveqy. Not a rewrite, L'Hospital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps 
$$ \lim_{z\to 0} \left[\frac{\sin z}{e^z-1}\right] =\frac{\sin 0}{e^0-1} =\frac{0}{1-1}=\frac{0}{0}$$
Now we can apply L'Hospital's rule
$$ \lim_{z\to 0} \left[\frac{\sin z}{e^z-1}\right] = \lim_{z\to 0} \left[\frac{\frac{d}{dz}[\sin z]}{\frac{d}{dz}\left[e^z-1\right]}\right] $$
$$= \lim_{z\to 0} \left[\frac{\cos z}{e^z}\right]=\frac{\cos 0}{e^0} =\frac{1}{1}=1$$